# Is it possible to generate a brand new spreadsheet from an existing one using google appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The title says it all. I can't find a function or code that lets me create a new spreadsheet from my existing one.

I honestly have no context for this, I'm just experimenting with what I can and can't do with app script google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use the SpreadsheetApp [Spreadsheet.copy(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String))